# Facebook Face recognition Twins

Tags: facebook, computer-vision, face-recognition

I was talking to my friend recently and he told me that Facebook could identify him and his twin. Identify meaning differentiate between them during tagging when they were present in the same photo.

How does Facebook do it? For face detection you need to extract features and use/compare them. Considering identical twins, won't their features be the same?

It is also possible that, since I asked just one person, I might be wrong. If so, is there any research being conducted on the same?

Comment: "They are identical twins" - obviously they aren't!

Comment: @MitchWheat Sorry, sorry. My bad :P

Comment: @MitchWheat How? And how do I improve?

Comment: Mitch Wheat meant that this question is not suitale for SO site. Maybe for SuperUser for example.

Comment: As far as I know, Facebook (previously Face.com) are currently the state of the art in face recognition. You can take a look at their paper - DeepFaces.